# Combine single-dimensional array with multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to combine a single-dimensional array with a multi-dimensional array. I see that there is an `array_combine` function and an `array_merge` function, but they don't seem to give me the result I need. I have the following arrays:

```
$days = Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 3 
        [1] => 6 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 6 
        [1] => 12 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 2 
        [1] => 4 
    )
)

$names = Array ( 
    [0] => Joe Smith 
    [1] => John Doe 
    [2] => Jack Frost
)
```

and this is the result I get when using `array_merge($days,$names)`:

```
$result = Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 3 
        [1] => 6 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 6 
        [1] => 12 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 2 
        [1] => 4 
    ) 
    [3] => Joe Smith 
    [4] => John Doe 
    [5] => Jack Frost 
)
```

How do I get the following result:

```
$result = Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => John Smith
        [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => 3 
            [1] => 6
        )
    ) 
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => John Doe
        [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => 6 
            [1] => 12 
        )
    ) 
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => Jack Frost
        [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => 2 
            [1] => 4 
        )
    )
)
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @JonathanM would it be easier to put the value of the single-level array as the key in the multi-level array. For example: `'John Smith' => array(...)`

Comment: that depends on what you want as output. If you change what you want as output, you can always make it "easier".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using example #4 from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for `array_map()`, here's a cool way to do it:

```
$result = array_map(null, $names, $days);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks